# Where is the add a game button in Steam?

Tags: steam

I just bought a digital copy of Grand Theft Auto 4 from Amazon, and I was given a Steam key to use.

The problem I have is that I do not see any button in Steam that allows you to add a game to your Library.

I've looked under the "Games" tag and have tried the methods described in various YouTube videos, but still no luck in solving my problem.

It's as if my browser is missing a row of selections at the upper part of the screen and, as I said earlier, there is no add a game button visible in the lower left of the Library.

Comment: There should be a redeem a code menu option, though.  I'm pretty sure Amazon gives you directions on how to redeem your code.  Did you read that?

Answer (score 27):

From your question it seems like you're using the in-browser version of Steam (http://store.steampowered.com/).

If this is the case, you will be unable to install your game until you download the Steam application, which can be found here: [Steam download](http://store.steampowered.com/about/)

After downloading, installing, and then opening this application, click the large text that says "LIBRARY", and then click "+ ADD A GAME" at the bottom left hand corner of the app. From here, the process for installing your game is very simple, just follow the app's instructions.

[image: Screenshot of process]

Comment: Hehe, I've never noticed that add a game option at the bottom of steam.  I've always used zajd's awnser.

Answer (score 7):

1. Click "Games" in the Menu Bar
2. Click "Activate a Product on Steam"
3. Follow Instructions

Answer (score 1):

1. On the top left corner, click on the word Steam:

[image]

2. Scroll to *Activate Products*
3. Follow the steps and enter your key.

Comment: Which steam skin is that?

Comment: http://forums.steampowered.com/forums/showthread.php?t=2989566